# Multiple UITextField inside UIScrollView not clickable after certain count

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextfield

So, I have created a `VerticalView` that handles adding multiple views inside `scrollview`, It also handles `scrollview` content size. Its defined like this :

```
import UIKit

class VerticalLayout: UIView {

    var yOffsets: [CGFloat] = []
    var heightValue : CGFloat = 0.0

    init(width: CGFloat) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:width, height:0))
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {

        var height: CGFloat = 0

        for i in 0..<subviews.count {
            let view = subviews[i] as UIView
            view.layoutSubviews()
            height += yOffsets[i]
            view.frame.origin.y = height
            height += view.frame.height
        }

        self.frame.size.height = height
        self.heightValue = height

        self.frame.size.height = height

        self.heightValue = height

        let ff = self.superview

        let dd = ff?.superview as! UIScrollView

        dd.contentSize = CGSize.init(width: self.frame.size.width, height: height)

    }

    override func addSubview(_ view: UIView) {
        yOffsets.append(view.frame.origin.y)
        super.addSubview(view)
    }

    func removeAll() {
        for view in subviews {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        yOffsets.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

    }

}
```

And My `View Controller` looks like this :

```
import UIKit
import os.log

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var contentview: UIView!


    @IBOutlet var scrollview: UIScrollView!
    let colors = [UIColor.red,UIColor.green,UIColor.blue,UIColor.magenta,UIColor.yellow]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        contentview.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        let vLayout = VerticalLayout(width: view.frame.width)
        vLayout.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        contentview.addSubview(vLayout)
        for i in 0..<14
        {
            vLayout.addSubview(getView(vLayout.frame.width,color: colors[i % colors.count]))
        }
    }

    func getView(_ width: CGFloat,color:UIColor) -> UIView
    {
        let view = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:width, height:100))
        view.backgroundColor = color
        view.placeholder = "Write here"
        return view
    }

}
```

This is viewcontroller view :

[image: Image showing view hierarchy]

And the `constrains` for `contentview` are :

[image: constrains]

And My `UITextField` are clickable only upto 10-12 TextFields depending upon device size. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up constraints of `contentView`. You need only two of them - equal width and equal height with parent `scrollView`.

Also I would do some advices: the way you create layout is not efficient, you should be using `UITableView` or `UiCollectionView`, cuz you can reuse the views / cells.

Also you can customize `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. It gives you a lot of possibilities and keeping your code clean.

Comment: Hi, this is just a test project that I created to test multiple textfield inside Scrollview. My main project has too many different views so they cannot be reused.

Comment: Why they cannot be reused ? Even with 100 custom cells - views u can reuse them, free them from memory after they getting out of bounds.